# Concatenate an ISet using Aggregate

Tags: c#, set-theory

I am trying to use `Concat()` on multiple ISets to make one larger ISet. So I tried the following piece of code:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Dictionary<Bii, ISet<Faa>> items = new Dictionary<Bii, ISet<Faa>>();

    public ISet<Faa> GetCompleteList()
    {
        ISet<Faa> result = items.Values.Aggregate((x,y) => x.Concat(y));
        return result;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this results in a Compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Faa>` to `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<Faa>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

And a second error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type `System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.ISet<Faa>,System.Collections.Generic.ISet<Faa>,System.Collections.Generic.ISet<Faa>>` because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

I also tried using a cast like:

```
ISet<Faa> result = items.Values.Aggregate((x,y) => (ISet<Faa>)x.Concat(y));
```

But this will give me an `InvalidCastException`, because it should be a `ConcatIterator` or some sort.

How can I do a good cast to join all ISets to one ISet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ functions such as `Concat` returns an `IEnumerable`. There is no `ISet` anymore after this call. You can rebuild one though:

```
ISet<Faa> result = new HashSet<Faa>(items.Values.Aggregate((x,y) => x.Concat(y)));
```

Or, using `SelectMany` to simplify:

```
ISet<Faa> result = new HashSet<Faa>(items.Values.SelectMany(value => value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
ISet<Faa> result = items.Values.Aggregate(new HashSet<Faa>(),
                                          (a, x) => { a.UnionWith(x)); return a; });
```

Comment: Although [Julien's second suggestion using `SelectMany`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955373/concatenate-an-iset-using-aggregate/6955450#6955450) is preferable, imo.

Comment: And could you also tell me why? Is it faster?

Comment: @Marnix: I think the `SelectMany` version is simpler and more readable. I'd expect the performance to be almost exactly the same (the `HashSet<T>` constructor probably uses `UnionWith` or equivalent behind-the-scenes anyway). You'd have to benchmark to be certain though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change any of the incoming sets you can do something like this:

```
public ISet<Faa> GetCompleteList()
{
    ISet<Faa> result = new HashSet<Faa>(items.Values.SelectMany(x => x));
    return result;
}
```

If you don't want to introduce a concrete type you could append to the first incoming Set but then you would have altered that which is less than stellar.